# How to stretch and center image in IE (CSS)?

Tags: css

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/kHT8z/8/
It's written that way cause IE don't support css's background-size.
I want to stretch the images center the thumbnail image proportionally with width 100% and to center it. How to do that (I want it to work in IE6)

Answer (score 0):

Via Chris Coyier: http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/

This code will let ie do background-size:cover. Just avoiding using it on the body or html tags and it should work fine. (Don't forget to change '.mybackground.jpg' to your image)

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```